# How to use selenium web driver to refer to the running instance of web browser?

Tags: c#, java, visual-c++, selenium, spy++

I want to change text in the `TextBox` in Web Page of currently opened web browser(Chrome, FF,IE).

After many unsuccessful searched I got to know that it can be possible using `selenium web Driver`.
But the problem is that I don't know how to use it. :(

So please tell me how I can use `Selenium Web Driver`?

Can I connect selenium with Already opened web browser?

Thank You In Advance.

Comment: No. Each WebDriver will control its' own browser window(s), and I don't think you can automate a previously running browser window.

Comment: Is there any way to do it?

Comment: oh, its bad, any ways thank you for support

Comment: @AnkitB Sorry to learn that Selenium can't attach to a running instance. :-(

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the oldest and possibly most requested features.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18

Sadly, it is not yet implemented.  Happily, the selenium project is open source!  All it needs is for someone who has the ability and desire to solve this problem to submit a patch.